# How to Prevent Page Break in TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a block of text like this:

```
<h2> This is heading</h2>

<p> This is a paragraph</p>
```

The page is breaking after the h2, and I want it to stick together with the following paragraph.

I have tried wrapping both elements in a html element (div, span), applying a class to them, and put this CSS in style tags at the beginning of the html to be printed in TCPDF:

```
page-break-inside:avoid
```

But it still breaks the page.

Other settings I have which may be relevant:

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 35);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
<p class="inline-object"><h2 class="inline-object">This is heading</h2> This is a paragraph</p>
```

Add CSS:

.inline-object{display:inline}

Comment: I downvoted this because having an `<h2>` inside a `<p>` is improper hierarchical format